# Create chsarp documentation string by code

Tags: c#, reflection, documentation, system.reflection

My goal is to use [this roslyn banned api analyzer](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn-analyzers/blob/master/src/Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.BannedApiAnalyzers/BannedApiAnalyzers.Help.md) to ban most methods in System.Linq.Enumerable.

I want to somehow generate these method document strings. ([documentation](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/master/spec/documentation-comments.md#id-string-format)) .

Example:

```
namespace Acme
{
    struct ValueType
    {
        public void M(int i) {...}
    }

    class Widget: IProcess
    {
        public class NestedClass
        {
            public void M(int i) {...}
        }

        public static void M0() {...}
        public void M1(char c, out float f, ref ValueType v) {...}
        public void M2(short[] x1, int[,] x2, long[][] x3) {...}
        public void M3(long[][] x3, Widget[][,,] x4) {...}
        public unsafe void M4(char *pc, Color **pf) {...}
        public unsafe void M5(void *pv, double *[][,] pd) {...}
        public void M6(int i, params object[] args) {...}
    }

    class MyList<T>
    {
        public void Test(T t) { }
    }

    class UseList
    {
        public void Process(MyList<int> list) { }
        public MyList<T> GetValues<T>(T inputValue) { return null; }
    }
}

"M:Acme.ValueType.M(System.Int32)"
"M:Acme.Widget.NestedClass.M(System.Int32)"
"M:Acme.Widget.M0"
"M:Acme.Widget.M1(System.Char,System.Single@,Acme.ValueType@)"
"M:Acme.Widget.M2(System.Int16[],System.Int32[0:,0:],System.Int64[][])"
"M:Acme.Widget.M3(System.Int64[][],Acme.Widget[0:,0:,0:][])"
"M:Acme.Widget.M4(System.Char*,Color**)"
"M:Acme.Widget.M5(System.Void*,System.Double*[0:,0:][])"
"M:Acme.Widget.M6(System.Int32,System.Object[])"
"M:Acme.MyList`1.Test(`0)"
"M:Acme.UseList.Process(Acme.MyList{System.Int32})"
"M:Acme.UseList.GetValues``(``0)"
```

Is there any kind of build in way? Would you build these strings using reflection?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.getproperties?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: I found that there is this roslyn class 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.codeanalysis.documentationcommentid?view=roslyn-dotnet

I'm doing it with that no.